# More than one initial migration file in a django project

Tags: python, django

In my project, to recreate the migrations, I removed all the migration files, leaving only the "initial.py" intact. Following that, I dropped my PostgreSQL database and executed the "makemigrations" command. In some of the applications, it generated more than one migration file, such as "0001_initial.py" and "0002_initial.py." Is this behavior considered normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is normal. Sometimes django splits the migrations to two files based on some logic. You can read it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/#django.db.migrations.Migration.initial) in the official docs.

From the docs

```
The “initial migrations” for an app are the migrations that create the first version of that app’s tables. Usually an app will have one initial migration, but in some cases of complex model interdependencies it may have two or more.
```

Make sure when you re-create migrations, you remove all migration files using the following commands and then run `makemigrations`

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

See this [article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) for more details about resetting migrations